# Rasa 3.0 Slot mapping from text issue

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu

Im using rasa 3.0 and I have a form with more than 5 slots,all are float type so I choose the mapping from text to set the slot from the last user utterance, but Im facing unexpected behavior like if I provide from text only the form will not be activated :
[from text only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PXA7.png)

and if I choose the intent: None  will not recognize the user input it seem to be looking for the intent name: None for nlu training example like so:
[from text with intent:None](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Tfe.png)
the only way form will work properly is by choosing from intent but the issue with this method is it required a constant value as per my understanding this value will feel the slot no matter the actual user input like so:
[from intent with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpiPn.png)
i hope some one can help me figure out how to use “from_text” mapping properly,

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this :

```yaml
mappings:
- type: from_text
  not_intent: stop
```